# Python Scrapy unicode comparing string Turkish characters

Tags: python, string, unicode, scrapy, compare

I researched many times this problem but i could not find clear answer. Please help me how can i compare two unicode strings. I want to get date from this format "17 Ağustos 2017" or "11 Eylül 2017" and I try to convert to this format "17-08-2017" , "11-9-2017" . But when i get the month string it returns

> "Ağustos" > "A\xc4\x9fustos" ,"Eylül" > "Eyl\xfcl"

```
    months = ['Ocak', '\xc5\x9eubat', 'Mart', 'Nisan', 
               'May\xc4\xb1s', 'Haziran', 'Temmuz', 
              'A\xc4\x9fustos', 'Eyl\xfcl', 'Ekim', 
                'Kas\xc4\xb1m', 'Aral\xc4\xb1k'
             ]

                month= valuesDetails[indexDate].split(" ")

                if int(months.index(month[1])+1 < 10): # month
                    month[-2]= "0"+str(months.index(month[1])+1)
                else:
                    month[-2]= str(months.index(month[1])+1)
                if int(month[0]) < 10: # day
                    mont[0] = "0"+month[0]


                item['date'] = month[0]+"-"+month[1]+"-"+month[2]
```

Comment: Does the environment where you are printing the output support unicode? For example, if you printing "Ağustos" in the shell without support for unicode, than you will get things like "A\xc4\x9fustos". That said, is always better to use standard libraries to work with dates than try to implement your own.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way of doing this is to use Python's `datetime` & `locale` libraries given we know [Turkish's locale code](https://lh.2xlibre.net/locale/tr_TR/), `tr_TR`, and some [datetime masking](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior).

```
#coding:utf8
from datetime import datetime
import locale

# Datetime is aware of locale,
# change locale to Turkish
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, "tr_TR")

dates = ['17 Ağustos 2017','11 Eylül 2017']

for date in dates:
    # Make `date` str a datetime object
    # using a datetime mask
    dt = datetime.strptime(date, '%d %B %Y')
    # Convert `dt` datetime object to
    # str in preferred format using a
    # datetime mask
    dt_str = dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
    # Walla!
    print(dt_str)
```

Output:

```
17-08-2017
11-09-2017
```

Comment: it returns >  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 581, in setlocale
    return _setlocale(category, locale)
Error: unsupported locale setting

Comment: Linux Mint default language us_US.UTF-8

Comment: There should be a locale code for Turkish, it's just a matter of finding what the code is. See: https://winaero.com/blog/add-locale-linux-mint/. And if this is too much for your use case, I can come up with an alternative answer if you'd like.

Comment: Actually i wonder how to compare unicode ? Myfriend solved my problem in different way but i still wonder comparing.. if you share your knowledge i will be happy. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the locale, you could create a global dictionary of the respective months and replace the Turkish month with the corresponding English month:

```
#coding:utf8
from datetime import datetime

MONTHS = {
    'Ocak': 'January',
    'Şubat': 'February',
    'Mart': 'March',
    'Nisan': 'April',
    'Mayıs': 'May',
    'Haziran': 'June',
    'Temmuz': 'July',
    'Ağustos': 'August',
    'Eylül': 'September',
    'Ekim': 'October',
    'Kasım': 'November',
    'Aralık': 'Decemeber'
}

def format_date(date):
    # Iterate through months and grab
    # respective turkish and english
    # month
    for tr_month, eng_month in MONTHS.items():
        # Replace turkish month (if found)
        # with english month
        if tr_month in date:
            print("'%s' > %s" % (tr_month, repr(tr_month)))
            date = date.replace(tr_month, eng_month)
            break
    # Convert date to datetime object and
    # back into the preferred format
    return datetime.strptime(date,'%d %B %Y').strftime('%d-%m-%Y')

for date in ['17 Ağustos 2017','11 Eylül 2017']:
    print(format_date(date))
```

Output:

```
'Ağustos' > 'A\xc4\x9fustos'
17-08-2017
'Eylül' > 'Eyl\xc3\xbcl'
11-09-2017
```

I'm assuming I got the months correct but I don't know Turkish so you might want to double check that.

Comment: Thank you. But my important point is learning unicode comparing

Comment: @adnankaya It is still comparing unicode, the `print()` function is just printing out the "rendered" unicode (i.e. Eylül instead of Eyl\xc3\xbcl). To show the "unrendered" unicode you can use `repr(some_unicode_str)`. I updated the code to print that out.